# distcc - are there cases it requires a synchronized network filesystem

Tags: makefile, distcc

Two simplified makefiles

**makefile1**

```
a.txt:
    echo “123144234” > a.txt

t2: a.txt
    cat a.txt > b.txt
```

**makefile2**

```
t1:
    echo “123144234” > a.txt

t2: t1
    cat a.txt > b.txt
```

Both makefiles have the same functionality.

Both makefiles can be run in parallel because the dependency *of* `t2` *on* `t1`.

However, there is a critical difference which *might?/does?* make a difference when it comes to distributed builds.

In **makefile1**, `t2` depends directly on the artifact `a.txt` which is also the same as the name of the target itself `a.txt`. However, in **makefile2**, while the recipe and artifact of `t1` is same as for `a.txt`, the name of the target is not `a.txt`.

This difference is key because `gnu make` (and I assume `distcc`) does NOT parse the recipe - nor analyze the filesystem at runtime - to determine all the artifacts for a given target. In **makefile2**, `gnu make` does NOT create ANY relationship between `a.txt` and `t1`.

When the build is done as `make -j` i.e. parallel but not distributed, this difference is irrelevant because all `make` targets are run *on the same machine* i.e. all the `make` instances access the same filesystem.

But let's consider what *could?/does?* happen during a distributed build if the two targets are built on two separate **machines**

In both makefiles, the recipe for `t2` would be run AFTER the recipe for `a.txt`/`t1`.

However, in **makefile1** the dependency of `t2` on `a.txt` is explicit i.e. `distcc` **knows** that to `make t2` on a separate machine, it must send the file `a.txt` to that separate machine.

**QUESTION**

1. If **makefile2** is run using `distcc`, without a synchronized distributed filesystem, and `t2` is `make`d on another machine, will there be a build error because `a.txt` is not present on the other machine?
2. What are the options for a distributed Linux filesystem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`distcc`](https://github.com/distcc/distcc) is merely a replacement for `gcc`. It uses local `gcc` to preprocess the source file, then sends it for compilation to another machine, receives back the object file and saves it into the local filesystem. `distcc` doesn't require a shared network filesystem or clock synchronization between the participating hosts.

There is alse new "pump" functionality that preprocesses on remote servers, but it doesn't require a shared network filesystem or clock synchronization either.

Your `make` always runs locally.

Answering your questions:

1. `distcc` doesn't run `make`. `make` runs `distc` instead of `gcc`. `make` examines dependencies and their timestamps locally.
2. `make` runs locally and it doesn't care whether the filesystem it uses is local or networked.

Comment: It makes sense that only the compile command, rather than an entire `make` recipe, is run on other machines. Then, you don't need to care about my case at all.

Comment: @Bob The recipe also runs locally. It runs `distcc` locally, which, under the hood, communicates with `distcc` servers.